# Laravel Migration: 2 different tables with the same blueprint/structure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I need 2 MySQL tables such as: `history` , `history_archive` to have the exact same structure,

The `history_archive` table is used to move items from `history` table and having fewer rows there for faster queries in `history` table (instead of just marking them as Archived in the same table)

I thought of having 2 migrations, but these 2 tables need to be exactly same to move items between them and I don't tthink copy/paste of every column is a good idea!

What is the best practice here?

I know the following is possible:

```
Schema::create('history', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    // ... extra columns 
});

// Exactly the same structure as above
Schema::create('history_archive', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    // I don't want to copy paste every column from history table here...
});
```

**But my question is:** How can I write the blueprint/construction only once, and pass it to both `Schema::create()` (and have 2 tables with different names, but same structure)

What I need is something like this (which doesn't work):

```
// Write blueprint only once
$table = new Blueprint();
$table->increments('id');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
// ... extra columns 

Schema::create('history', function () use ($table) {
    $table;
});

Schema::create('history_archive', function () use ($table) {
    $table;
});
```

Comment: You can create many tables in same migration. But i don't understand what you mean by "I don't want to copy paste every column from history table here..."

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Like I said, those 2 tables have exactly the same columns/structure, so my question is how can I write the blueprint/construction only once, and pass it to both `Schema::create()` (and have 2 tables with different names, but same structure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create many tables in same migration. If all the tables have exactly the same structure, and you don't want to copy paste every column, I think you can do something like this:

```
$tables = ['history', 'history_archive'];
foreach($tables as $tablename) {
    Schema::create($tablename, function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        // ... extra columns 
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was so focused on passing the blueprint to 2 Schemas, that I totally missed this. smart and works fine, Thank you!